# How to check if a file can be previewed (images, videos, audios or text files) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm building kind of a file cloud and I'm trying to show users a preview button just if the file uploaded it's not damaged or it can be opened/readed. How can I check that in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a function to check if file is damaged and an other to check if file is readable.
For the first, let's name it isDamaged(), the easiest would be to verify the hash of the file. But you would have to set up a file/hash process on your server. Indeed your files should have been downloaded from somewhere, from a site where files come along with their proper hash.
For the second function, let's name it isReadable() you'll have to associate the suffix (.jpeg - .pdf - .gif  …) with app to test its readability.